# How to extract address balance

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract BTC address while checking it via blockchain.info

My code:

```
<?php

$url1= "https://blockchain.info/balance?cors=true&active=1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq";
$value1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$data = json_decode($value1);
$FinalBalance1 = $data["final_balance"];
echo $FinalBalance1;

?>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\laragon\www\balancechecker\test.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\laragon\www\balancechecker\test.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\laragon\www\balancechecker\test.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\laragon\www\balancechecker\test.php on line 5
```

What I'm missing? I'm just learning please bear with me. Thank you

Another shot:

```
<?php
$url1= "https://blockchain.info/balance?cors=true&active=1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq";
$value1 = file_get_contents($url1,true);
$data = json_decode($value1);
$FinalBalance1 = $data->final_balance;
echo $FinalBalance1;

?>
```

Error I'm getting:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$final_balance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the [associative](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) parameter. Without this parameter set to `true`, `json_decode($value1)` will return an object.

Alternatively you could change `$data["final_balance"]` to `$data->final_balance`. Depending on what you prefer.

**Edit:**

It seems that you use the result wrong. Visiting the URL via browser shows, that the data has the key `1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq`.

A fixed Version could be:

```
$url1= "https://blockchain.info/balance?cors=true&active=1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq";
$value1 = file_get_contents($url1,true);
$data = json_decode($value1, true);
$FinalBalance1 = $data['1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq']['final_balance'];
echo $FinalBalance1;
```

**Edit:**

A version with btc address as parameter.

```
$address = "1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq";
$url1= "https://blockchain.info/balance?cors=true&active=".$address;
$value1 = file_get_contents($url1,true);
$data = json_decode($value1, true); # <- note the second parameter
$FinalBalance1 = $data[$address]['final_balance'];
echo $FinalBalance1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that however I'm getting another error: `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$final_balance Line 5 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$final_balance`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks alot, now it works, do we have to repeat the btc address in $FinalBalance variable?

Comment: if $address is a variable can we do something like this: `$FinalBalance1 = $data->$address['final_balance'];` I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Try `$FinalBalance1 = $data[$address]['final_balance'];`

Comment: Error `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 1BmXhLP1wkbDwgpPbdB57L7KrwBN9Q9Dkq`

Comment: I've added a version with btc address as parameter.

Comment: it works now, I don't understand what is the change as I had 'true' parameter on both in url1 and JSON decode, thanks alot